# the intermediate value theorem and the commutative composite of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ two continuous  fucntions defined from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. Suppose that

$(\forall x\in [0,1]) : g  \circ f(x)= f  \circ g(x)$.

Prove that:

$ (\exists \alpha \in [0,1]) : f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$.

I considered the function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, but I don't know how to prove that $\:h(0).h(1)< 0\:$ to use the the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I=[0,1]$. Put $E=\{x\in I; f(x)=x\}$. Then $E$ is not empty, as $\varphi(x)=f(x)-x$ is such that $\varphi(0)=f(0)\geq 0$, and $\varphi(1)=f(1)-1\leq 0$. This is also a closed subset of $[0,1]$. By the hypothesis, if $x\in E$, then $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=g(x)$, hence $g(x)\in E$. Let now $m={\rm inf}(E)$, $M={\rm Sup}(E)$ ($m,M\in E$ as $E$ is closed). Put $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.  We have $g(m)\in E$, hence $g(m)\geq m=f(m)$, hence $h(m)\leq 0$. We have $g(M)\in E$, hence $g(M)\leq M=f(M)$, hence $h(M)\geq 0$. Hence there exists $u$, such that $h(u)=0$.

Comment: Thank you @Kelenner for the beautiful your responce.

Comment: You are welcome.